# Not allowing alphabets or other symbols than numerics (0-9) or decimal in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, browser, textbox, decimal

Following code worked for me on : `firefox`, `IE 8`, `chrome`, `Safari` and `iphone`.

```
function dotplaced(myfield){
    if(myfield.indexOf(".")===-1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;    
}

function NumbersOnly(myfield, e) {
    var key;
    var keychar;

    if (window.event) {
        key = window.event.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e) {
        key = e.which;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

    keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

    // control keys
    if ((key == null) || (key == 0) || (key == 8) ||
    (key == 9) || (key == 13) || (key == 27)) {
        return true;
    }
    // numbers
    else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1)) {
        return true;
    }
    // decimal point jump
    else if (!dotplaced(myfield.value) && (keychar == ".")) {
        //myfield.form.elements[dec].focus();        
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

While Android 2.1 is giving some errors. If i dont have anything in textbox, android is allowing me to enter alphabets too, if i enter some default value say 7. Then, it is restricting until i enter a period sign or i delete all the text of textbox.Does anyone have any idea regarding this?

Comment: irony mode on: if it is giving "some errors" you should "do some(thing)" to avoid them

Comment: This is javascript, right? Could you please be much more specific and tell us, that you want to do a website/webapplication instead of a native application... its quite confusing just tagging the question with android...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion WarrenFaith. I am into web designing in which i need to restrict the user from entering alphabets or symbols for Android, iPhone and Blackberry. This code works for the desktop browsers and also for iPhone and Blackberry. But in Android, it is behaving incorrect. In Android too, if i give some default value say 7, it works ok. But as soon as i enter period sign or deletes textbox's content, it starts to take alphabets too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i did more research on this. Then i came to know that it is Android's behaviour of autotext predictions that is the cause of problem.

Answer (score 2):

maybe it is helpful to add `android:numeric="integer"` to the xml?

Comment: 2red13: Thanks for your reply. But t is not a native application. Instead i am into web designing which i need to support for Android, Blackberry and iPhone